# Multimodal (At least trimodal) distribution with equal magnitude mode and a positive skew

Tags: c++, math, statistics, skew, probability-density

Please help me to generate multimodal (at least tri-modal) distribution with equal magnitude mode and a positive skew in C++?

I don't know if there is a library for this or not. If not, them is it possible to generate such data points by any formula? Please help me on this.

Comment: You could create a mixture distribution using three normal distributions: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution.  Choose parameters and weights, then use the CDF to map from uniform(0, 1) variates to variates of your random variable. This technique is called "inverse transform sampling": http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling